# Problem querying new custom post type while old display fine

Tags: custom-post-types

I had existing custom post types, which I am able to query successfully. But newly registered custom post type does not show up, I have added 2 test posts, individually it shows up under post type site/slug/ but I want to display it on another page, results are not returning it there.

Following is the code I put for registering the new post type:

```
    $custom_post_types = array('proof-concept' => array(
    'labels' => array(
    'name'          => 'Proof of Concepts',
    'singular_name' => 'Proof of Concept'
    ),
    'taxonomies' => array('first', 'second','third'),
    'has_archive'=> true
    ))
    foreach($custom_post_types as $id=>$custom_post_type){
    if(!isset($custom_post_type['public']))
        $custom_post_type['public'] = true;
    register_post_type( $id, $custom_post_type);
```

Please note custom_post_types array does have other post types I removed from the code.

Here's the query:

```
   $query = new WP_Query(array('showposts' => -1, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'page', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ));
```

Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: Please note, I've already flushed rewrite rules. Posts are displaying fine when opened individually or when post type slug is opened.

Comment: your question is confusing. how does that query relate to the custom post type registration code?

Comment: Your query is for a 'page' post type, not your custom type ?

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for replying. Theme's developer has registered taxonomies as custom post types as well (like I registered mine), which makes it more confusing for me. Using query I mentioned above, it is pulling those taxonomies. Is there a way to include my custom post type in the query above or maybe register in a way that it gets pulled when above mentioned query runs? Gracious.